# How to work with IN operator in mysql ajax table editor

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a query in mysql that is:

```
select 
address,state,id 
from
addressdata 
where
address in (select address from addressdata group by address having count(*) > 1)
```

But I am facing a problem: how do I make that query work in Mysql Ajax Table Editor?

I have defined the columns in the mysql ajax table editor in the following way:

```
function initiateEditor()
{
    $tableColumns['ID'] = array(
        'display_text' => 'ID', 
        'perms' => 'VT', 
    );
    $tableColumns['State'] = array(
        'display_text' => 'State', 
        'perms' => 'VT', 
    );
    $tableColumns['Address'] = array(
        'display_text' => 'Address', 
        'perms' => 'VT', 
        'table_fun' => array(&$this,'formatLink'), 
        'view_fun' => array(&$this,'formatLink')
    );
}

function formatLink($col,$val,$row) 
{ 
    $query1=mysql_query("select Address from addressdata group by Address having count(*) > 1") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as normal query please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Use Some thing like this which may work for you

```
$this->Editor->setConfig('sqlFilters',"Address != '' and Address IN(select address from addressdata group by address having count(*) > 1)");
```